# eclipse can't find main method when I make a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar, manifest.mf

so I have the code made

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class main extends Application{
    public static void Main (String[] args){
        
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("title");
        Pane pain = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(main.class.getResource("gui.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pain));
        primaryStage.show();
        
        
    }
}
```

and it runs fine normally.

then I set up the configurations
Main class: application.main
project JRE jre1.8.0_251

and that runs just fine.

then I export/ Runnable JAR file
select that launch configuration

export to C:\Users\clark\OneDrive\Documents\FRM.jar

Extract required libraries

hit finish and the following pops up

Jar export finished with problems.
Could not find main method from given launch configuration.

MANIFEST.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main
Created-By: 13.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)
```

Comment: have you checked the manifest.mf file?

Comment: I will add it..

Comment: Put the main method below the start method and clean project. There is nothing inside the main method, Java is meant to run what is inside the main method which includes the class.

Comment: The class is `mypackage.main`, so the manifest line should be `Main-Class: mypackage.main`?

Comment: so non of that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main method is named wrong. Change

```
public static void Main (String[] args)
```

to

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

Note that the *m* needs to be lower case